# No implicit conversion in overloaded operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

`d1 + 4` works but `4 + d1` doesn't even though 4 can be converted implicitly to a GMan. Why aren't they equivalent?

```
struct GMan
{
    int a, b;

    GMan() : a(), b() {}
    GMan(int _a) : a(_a), b() {}
    GMan(int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {}

    GMan operator +(const GMan& _b)
    {
         GMan d;
         d.a = this->a + _b.a;
         d.b = this->b + _b.b;
         return d;
    }
};

int main()
{
    GMan d1(1, 2), d(2);
    GMan d3;
    d3 = d1 + 4; 
    d3 = 4 + d1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried asking [GMan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gman)?

Comment: @GMan's fan? Amazing. Where are my fans(if any)? `:P`

Comment: LOL is this SO's first ever gimmick account in the C++ tag?

Comment: I think one of these GMan's should be explicit :)

Comment: Wow. first day on SO, and already GMan's fan.

Comment: To get what you want, you just need the following line (outside the class definition): GMan operator +(int a, const GMan& b) { return b + a ; }  To get this to compile, you need to add 'const' to the in-class definition: 
GMan operator +(const GMan& _b) const

Comment: I like this question.

Comment: @MSalters:  Agreed.  I'm going omn the assumption that "GMan's Fan" == "GMan" until proven otherwise.  Hey it's cool, I'm not a hater. :)

Comment: @GMan:  Well, you wouldn't have asked it otherwise!  :)

Comment: @GMan ahaha, I'm your fan too. For sure, my worship happens in private though!

Comment: @Johannes : If you are @GMan's 1st fan then I am his 3rd fan (I won't change my name though `:P`)

Comment: @Prasoon I heard of that troll too who is called "Johannes". But he's not his first fan. I'm already.

Comment: @Johannes : Haha! But I am your 1st fan. Does that mean I am a 1st fan of a 1st fan of GMan? ;-)

Comment: @GMan's 1st: <3 (Except now you can't change your name for a month... :o!)

Comment: @GMan lol I had no clue about that name-changing limit thing. This is epic fail xD

Comment: @GMan: I don't think it's too bad. :P

Comment: @GMan's 1st Fan:  Well, at least you didn't change your name to "Unicorns are Yummy" (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/add-warning-when-changing-display-name)  :-)

Comment: @Johannes: First? Ha, look again! Who commented first on this issue? Coming late to the table and then grabbing for the biggest piece of meat...

Comment: @James thanks mate you saved my month! Here have this nice piece of meat :)

Comment: If you're going to define ctors that way, you might as well just define one with default parameter values.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A call `x + y` is translated by the C++ compiler into either of the following two calls (depending on whether `x` is of class type, and whether such a function exists):

1. Member function

   ```
   x.operator +(y);
   ```
2. Free function

   ```
   operator +(x, y);
   ```

Now C++ has a simple rule: no implicit conversion can happen before a member access operator (`.`). That way, `x` in the above code cannot undergo an implicit conversion in the first code, but it can in the second.

This rule makes sense: if `x` could be converted implicitly in the first code above, the C++ compiler wouldn’t know any more which function to call (i.e. which class it belongs to) so it would have to search *all existing classes* for a matching member function. That would play havoc with C++’ type system and make the overloading rules even more complex and confusing.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165072/no-implicit-conversion-in-operator-overloading/4165125#4165125) answer is correct. Those points then entail the canonical way of implementing such operators:

```
struct GMan
{
    int a, b;

    /* Side-note: these could be combined:
    GMan():a(),b(){}
    GMan(int _a):a(_a),b(){}
    GMan(int _a, int _b):a(_a),b(_b){}
    */
    GMan(int _a = 0, int _b = 0) : a(_a), b(_b){} // into this

    // first implement the mutating operator
    GMan& operator+=(const GMan& _b)
    {
        // the use of 'this' to access members
        // is generally seen as noise
        a += _b.a;
        b += _b.b;

        return *this;
    }
};

// then use it to implement the non-mutating operator, as a free-function
// (always prefer free-functions over member-functions, for various reasons)
GMan operator+(GMan _a, const GMan& _b)
{
    _a += b; // code re-use
    return _a;
}
```

And so on for other operators.